# extract image from curl result

Tags: php, image, curl

I need to display an image from a url using CURL.but after running this code i could only get textual data. no image is displayed?the $one contains captcha image and i want the user to fill the captcha by seeing image.plz help...

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$usergaent );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sitproject.com/verification.asp?source=login' );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,"http://site2sms.com/login.asp");
$one = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $one;


while debugging $one contains this only no binary image data:

<body>
<div class="success">Thanks for using Sitproject.Com! You are logged into your Account Successfully to Proceed Further Please Enter Below Displayed 3 Digits Security Code in the Input Box!</div>
<table width="1079" height="54" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>
<img src="security/captcha.asp" />
<br />
Please Type the 3 Digits Displayed above in the Image and Click on Proceed Further Button to use the Free Services?
<br />
<form name="frmVerify" action="auth.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="txtSource" value="captcha" />
<input type="text" name="txtCaptcha" maxlength="3" />
<input type="submit" value="Proceed Further" />
</form>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Note: If you are having any problem with Security Code you can mail us at support@sitproject.com!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you even _read_ the message in the HTML response …?

Answer (score 1):

You need a second request, to request the captcha image, which from looking at the response, is in:

```
security/captcha.asp
```

I would say given that there is a captcha, they probably don't want bots such as this trying to consume the service, so you need to verify you aren't violating any terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your Situation

```
<?php 
$url = "https://api.github.com/users/softvar"; //enter url to extract from
$send_curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'softvar'); // your useragent name
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json', "Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($send_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$json_response = curl_exec($send_curl);
echo $json_response; // response in JSON
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
echo '</br></br>';

$img =  $response['avatar_url']; // instead of 'avatar_url' enter the element name which contains the image url

//while debugging $one contains this only no binary image data:
?>
<body>
<div class="success">Thanks for using Sitproject.Com! You are logged into your Account Successfully to Proceed Further Please Enter Below Displayed 3 Digits Security Code in the Input Box!</div>
<table width="1079" height="54" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $img;?>" />
<!-- Your captcha will display here-->
<br />
Please Type the 3 Digits Displayed above in the Image and Click on Proceed Further Button to use the Free Services?
<br />
<form name="frmVerify" action="auth.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="txtSource" value="captcha" />
<input type="text" name="txtCaptcha" maxlength="3" />
<input type="submit" value="Proceed Further" />
</form>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Note: If you are having any problem with Security Code you can mail us at support@sitproject.com!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

It's a fully working example. Try it.

This is the way how you fetch something. In response, you will get data as per your CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. Here i have used `JSON`.

Then extract the image_url you simply want and put wherever you want.

If this solves your problem, do click to accept this.

Comment: header("Content-Type: image/bmp");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=captcha.bmp");
echo $one;

Comment: i have to transfer this code to seprate php otherwise it will not work.because page header is changed to image/bmp.